# Python, Flask - TypeError: string index indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, flask

Goal: Print out the values of a dictionary via a for loop

Here is a **recreated** version of the code as reference (not the actual code, works just the same):

```
import networkx as nx
random_dictionary = {
"name": "DAG",
"children": "None",
"father": "None",
"mother": "None",
"spouse": "None",
}

serializable_format = random_dictionary

for n in serializable_format:
    print("[+] node: " + n + ", edge: " + str(serializable_format[n]['pre_transactions']))
    for x in serializable_format[n]['pre_transactions']:
        ledger.add_edge(n, x)
```

When I execute it, I am constantly met with the following error...

```
TypeError: string index indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I can not insert an integer in the `[n]` section, as that would give me the following error

```
KeyError: (insert any number here)
```

So how do I go about making a for loop which gets the content from the dictionary without encountering any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the answer in two.

First, to "Print out the values of a dictionary via a for loop" , as requested, you just do:

```
for k in serializable_format:
    print(serializable_format[k]
```

the loop iterates over the *keys* of the dictionary. You should check the official [documentation on dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), particularly the "Looping Techniques" part. You will find the use of `dict.items()` useful.

The problem in your code is that `serializable_format[n]` is a string ("DAG", 'None", etc). The expression `serializable_format[n]['pre_transactions']` tries to use the string `'pre_transactions'` for indexing the first string, raising a `TypeError`. Re-check your code, because you are mistaken those strings with some other type (like `dicts`), that can be accessed via keys (like `'pre_transactions'`). Maybe your dictionary should not be a dictionary of strings but of another kind of objects.

Note that your code has one loop nested inside another, so for each key you loop again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!! Alright, when I remove ['pre_transactions'], the code functions, but how exactly would you recommend incorporating ['pre_transactions'] back into the code, so it can function?

Comment: You are welcome. I expanded the answer giving some more information, but I think this is the answer of the question you posted. It is not possible to improve it without knowing what you expect to do. The ` ['pre_transactions']` part makes no sense. I guess you want to call `add_edge` with a (key, value) pair, but that is not the answer to the question you posted. I guess you want to do something in the line of `for k, v in serializable_format.items():
    print("[+] node: " + k + ", edge: " + str(serializable_format[k]))
    ledger.add_edge(k, v)
` , but It's only a guess.

Comment: That's exactly what I intended to do, thanks man!